# Honda Tyre Size and Numbers

Tags: honda, tires, wheels, accord

I have just purchased a used Honda Accord Euro 2005. I did not check the tyre number while purchasing. Yesterday one the tyres was bursted. Then I matched the tyre number mentioned in the door of the car and actually installed tyres. The recommended tyre numbers on the door were 205/55R16 91V ans 225/45R17 91W however, the tyre number of installed tyres was 215/40zr17. What do you recommend? Should I install 215/40zr17 or should I change all the four tyres? Additionally please let me know what is difference between 91V and 91W on tyres number. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the rim size, which I would assume to be 17".

The previous owner fitted a tire which was slightly narrower than specified - this will not usually make a difference.

The 91V and 91W are speed and load ratings - there are many tire shops etc detailing these details, but you should match what is fitted on the vehicle.

Here is but one site showing that information :

https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=35

Comment: The side profile is also smaller than the spec from the door jamb sticker. This means that overall, his wheels + tires are smaller than those sizes. But, I still agree, OP should just get another tire that is the same size as the current ones. If he has extra money to spare, he could get a new set of 4 that comply with the 225/45R17 spec.